# ValidateDataAnnotations in .Net 7 exists in one project but not in another in the same solution

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-7.0

I'm using .Net 7.

I have two class library projects in my solution that both need to register Options with data annotations. I'm doing this in

Below is a stripped down example.

```cs
// project 1
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection AddFeature1(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    IHostEnvironment environment
  )
  {

    /* snip */

    services.AddOptions<MyOptionsClass2>()
      .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptionsClass2)))
      .ValidateDataAnnotations(); // This works

    /* snip */

    return services;
  }
}
```

```cs
// project 2
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
  public static IServiceCollection AddFeature1(
    this IServiceCollection services,
    IConfiguration configuration,
    IHostEnvironment environment
  )
  {

    /* snip */

    services.AddOptions<MyOptionsClass2>()
      .Bind(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MyOptionsClass2)))
      .ValidateDataAnnotations(); // This does not work - Cannot resolve symbol 'ValidateDataAnnotations'

    /* snip */

    return services;
  }
}
```

What have I missed or done wrong?

Comment: I think you are missing Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations package, just check for it

Comment: @VivekNuna Thanks for the reply. That's supposed to be built-in now rather than an extra package. Neither of the class libraries have that, but one works and one doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ValidateDataAnnotations extension method is defined in the Microsoft.Extensions.Options.DataAnnotations NuGet package.
For web apps that use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK, this package is referenced implicitly from the shared framework.
But for other applications/projects you need to include package explicitly.